# Como criar um sub submenu usando megamenu do bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, submenu, nav-bar

Alguém sabe como deva criar um sub submenu com megamenus?
Obrigado

```css
        .navbar-default {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #39b3d7;
            border-color: #269abc;
        }
        
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
            color: #fff;
        }
        
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
            border-top-color: #fff;
            border-bottom-color: #fff;
        }
        
        .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
            color: #fff;
        }
        
        .menu-large {
            position: static !important;
        }
        
        .megamenu {
            padding: 20px 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .megamenu> li > ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        
        .megamenu> li > ul > li {
            list-style: none;
        }
        
        .megamenu> li > ul > li > a {
            display: block;
            padding: 3px 20px;
            clear: both;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1.428571429;
            color: #333333;
            white-space: normal;
        }
        
        .megamenu> li ul > li > a:hover,
        .megamenu> li ul > li > a:focus {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #262626;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
        
        .megamenu.disabled > a,
        .megamenu.disabled > a:hover,
        .megamenu.disabled > a:focus {
            color: #999999;
        }
        
        .megamenu.disabled > a:hover,
        .megamenu.disabled > a:focus {
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: transparent;
            background-image: none;
            filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }
        
        .megamenu.dropdown-header {
            color: #428bca;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            .megamenu {
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
            }
            .megamenu> li {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
            .megamenu> li:last-child {
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }
            .megamenu.dropdown-header {
                padding: 3px 15px !important;
            }
            .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
                color: #fff;
            }
        }
```

```html
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown menu-large">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown <b class="caret"></b> </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row">
                            <li>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                        <img src="img/a.png" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                        <img src="img/b.png" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                        <img src="img/c.png" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                
                                <!-- problema aqui -->
                                <li class="dropdown menu-large">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img src="img/d.png" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                        <b class="caret"></b> </a>

                                        <ul class="dropdown-submenu megamenu row">
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                    <img src="img/d1.png" />
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                    <img src="img/d2.png" />
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <!-- problema aqui -->

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Por questões de design, não faz sentido por um submenu num mega-menu.

Depois, dê uma olhada [nesse exemplo](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-slide-down-on-hover-with-carousel).

Comment: Não respondeu a pergunta principal amigo.

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO Ah, você é daqueles que gostam de respostas longas e digressivas. Desculpa! E não eu não sou seu amigo e nem vou incentivar PÉSSIMAS práticas de design, não se preocupe com isso. Bom senso quer dizer que nem todas as respostas devem ser respondidas ao pé da letra, você deveria saber disso, não?! A minha resposta final é essa: não coloque um submenu num MEGA MENU. Problemas de luso-brasileiros: sempre esquecem do conceito, das regras, do bom senso, dos princípios, dos fundamentos. Pare de ser um desses, faça-se um favor.

Comment: Opa, só falei por que talvez pessoas novas em design podem ficarem na dúvida. mas valeu por ser grosso deste jeito.